# Why this error happen "duplicated name in data frame using '.'?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 30 row and 850 column(features).
when I want to use svm or other classifier with caret and e1071 packages, I faced this error!

> ```
> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
>   duplicated name 'X10Percentile' in data frame using '.'
> ```

Even when I want to use feature selection method such as **Boruta**, I face the same error.
I double check my feature and found nothing.  I thought I must have the same column name in data frame so I create a sample data and check as follow:

```
test<-data.frame("w1"=c(1:6),"w1.1"=c(2:7),"w1"=c(3:8), "ta"=c("T","F","T","F","F","T"))

set.seed(100)
train <- createDataPartition(y=test$ta,p=0.6,list = FALSE)
TrainSet <- test[train,]
TestSet <- test[-train,]

trcontrol_rcv<- trainControl(method="cv", number=10) 
 
 svm_test<-svm(ta ~., data=TrainSet,trControl=trcontrol_rcv)
```

**It works good and no Error occurs.**
As I see no error happen when test data even has exactly the same colname.
I want to know why this error"Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
duplicated name 'X10Percentile' in data frame using '.'" happen for my data, and how can I eliminate  it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the packages used?

Comment: Can you change your code snippets to just code please ... if you put some spaces at the start of each line it will render as code. Or highlight each block and  press the code icon.  Right now when I read it I can't figure out which is the code that generates the error.

Comment: `data.frame("w1"=c(1:6),"w1.1"=c(2:7),"w1"=c(3:8),`  has `w1` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, everyone. Fortunately, I found the cause of this error.
Because  R considers variables as factors. Therefore it makes a data. frame (which in fact is a list).To solve this problem, I converted it into a data numeric in the following way;

```html
test1<-sapply(test,function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For me that was not the solution, I had a LargeMatrix as an object of only numeric type vectors.

**The problem was that some `dimnames(MyLargeMatrix)` were duplicated.** I change them and the error went away.